# Drawing SVG element on top with smooth transitions

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have a page with different SVG elements that react when hovering over them. When hovering, the element increases in size, covering neighbouring elements. My trouble is that some of the neighbours have been drawn later and won't be covered. [[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niC9h.png%20Example)]

I tried to fix the issue by using `appendChild()` when hovering over to make it the last drawn element, but this removes the smooth transition effect I set with CSS.

Example:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  for (var n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    var new_rect = document.getElementById("0").cloneNode(true);
    new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", i * 20 + 10);
    new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", n * 20 + 10);

    new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "id", i + n);
    document.getElementById("mainG").appendChild(new_rect);
  }
}

function expand(evt) {
  //evt.target.parentNode.appendChild(evt.target);
  evt.target.setAttributeNS(null, "r", "25");
}

function shrink(evt) {
  evt.target.setAttributeNS(null, "r", "10");
}
```

```css
.circle {
  fill: hsl(100, 30%, 80%);
  -webkit-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
}
.circle:hover {
  fill: hsl(0, 50%, 70%);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="440" height="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="mainG">
    <circle id="0" cx="10" cy="10" r="10" stroke="none" fill="white" class="circle" onmouseover="expand(evt)" onmouseout="shrink(evt)"></circle>
  </g>
  <g id="cloneG"></g>
</svg>
```

How can I both get the element to be drawn on top while still having smooth transitions between states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force a reflow with the following..

```
var test = evt.target.offsetHeight;
```

Do this just before changing the radius

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  for (var n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    var new_rect = document.getElementById("0").cloneNode(true);
    new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", i * 20 + 10);
    new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", n * 20 + 10);

    new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "id", i + n);
    document.getElementById("mainG").appendChild(new_rect);
  }
}

function expand(evt) {
  evt.target.parentNode.appendChild(evt.target);
  var test = evt.target.offsetHeight;
  evt.target.setAttributeNS(null, "r", "25");
}

function shrink(evt) {
  evt.target.setAttributeNS(null, "r", "10");
}
```

```css
.circle {
  fill: hsl(100, 30%, 80%);
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
.circle:hover {
  fill: hsl(0, 50%, 70%);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="440" height="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="mainG">
    <circle id="0" cx="10" cy="10" r="10" stroke="none" fill="white" class="circle" onmouseover="expand(evt)" onmouseout="shrink(evt)"></circle>
  </g>
  <g id="cloneG"></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly!  I'm pretty new to this, could you tell me what's going on? Why do I need to force a reflow?

Comment: Good question, and I'm not totally sure, I was just guessing it may help as you have 2 events happening (css can cache changes for optimisation), the css hover and the function call, and I was guessing repainting the elements would help. To get further understanding, you may need to ask it as another question, and maybe one of the browser svg/css experts may be able to clarify. You may also find it varies per browser, so I would do some testing with each.

Answer (score 0):

in this way you preserve the CSS transition :

```js
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  for (var n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    var new_rect = document.getElementById("0").cloneNode(true);
    new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", i * 20 + 10);
    new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", n * 20 + 10);

    new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "id", i + n);
    document.getElementById("mainG").appendChild(new_rect);
  }
}

function expand(evt) {
  evt.target.parentNode.appendChild(evt.target); 
  evt.target.setAttributeNS(null, "r", "25");
  evt.target.style.fill='hsl(0, 50%, 70%)';
}

function shrink(evt) {
  evt.target.setAttributeNS(null, "r", "10");
  evt.target.style.fill='hsl(100, 30%, 80%)';
}
```

```css
 .circle {
  fill: hsl(100, 30%, 80%);
  -webkit-transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="440" height="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="mainG">
    <circle id="0" cx="10" cy="10" r="10" stroke="none" fill="white" class="circle" onmouseover="expand(evt)" onmouseout="shrink(evt)"></circle>
  </g>
  <g id="cloneG"></g>
</svg>
```

or (same thing with CSS added through JS)

```js
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      for (var n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
        var new_rect = document.getElementById("0").cloneNode(true);
        new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", i * 20 + 10);
        new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", n * 20 + 10);
        new_rect.style.fill='hsl(100, 30%, 80%)';
        new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "id", i + n);
        document.getElementById("mainG").appendChild(new_rect);
          
      }
    }

    function expand(evt) {
      evt.target.parentNode.appendChild(evt.target); 
      evt.target.setAttributeNS(null, "r", "25");
      evt.target.style.fill='hsl(0, 50%, 70%)';
      evt.target.style.transition= '.4s ease-in-out';
    }

    function shrink(evt) {
      evt.target.setAttributeNS(null, "r", "10");
      evt.target.style.fill='hsl(100, 30%, 80%)';
    }
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="440" height="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g id="mainG">
        <circle id="0" cx="10" cy="10" r="10" stroke="none" fill="white" class="circle" onmouseover="expand(evt)" onmouseout="shrink(evt)"></circle>
      </g>
      <g id="cloneG"></g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: If I add the z-index and I remove the 'appendChild()' line, it is still behind the other elements :( I'm not sure the z-index works with svg elements.

Comment: No, svg is rendered by order, z-index is ignored

Comment: Thank you for your answers, however If the z-index worked in your original answer that would have fixed my problem. With your example the `expand()` function is still instant instead of a smooth transition (at least on Chrome), which is the part I'm struggling with.